# Can you compare a two-factor solution from CFA to a three-factor solution via Chi²-tests?

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I got a questionnaire with 30 items and our theory proposes two different factor solutions for this questionnaire. I want to run CFA based on this theory. Solution 1 would include 2 factors on which 15 items load, respectively. Solution 2 would include 3 factors on which different subsets of items would load.
My question is now whether these models would qualify as nested and I can thus compare their model-fit using Chi²-test or a likelihood ratio test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately these models are not nested. It is possible to test different factor structures using chi-square tests, but only if you are comparing models where one of the models splits a factor into more than one factor. For example, you can use a chi-square test to compare a 2-factor solution with Factor A comprising items 1-10 and Factor B comprising items 11-30, and a 3-factor solution with Factor A comprising items 1-10 Factor B* comprising items 11-20, and Factor C* comprising items 21-30. In this case, you are testing whether Factor B can be split into Factor B* and Factor C*. The reason these two models are nested is that the model with Factor B is equivalent to the model with Factors B* and C* when the correlation between Factors B* and C* is fixed a 1. Therefore, the test comparing the two models tests whether that restriction is valid.

Comparing models with completely different factor structures cannot be done using a chi-square test. You can use other methods of comparing models, like BIC, instead, though these do not provide formal tests.

Comment: NB The models are being fit on different items in this case, so AIC and BIC can't be used either! All you can really use here is informal comparisons of SEM fit indices (RMSEA,CFI, etc.), but even then you can't say if differences are due to one model being better, or some items being too noisy.

Comment: @Eoin I interpreted the question to say that the same items are being used but in different factor structures, i.e., *Solution 2 would include 3 factors on which different subsets  of* [the same 30] *items would load.*

Comment: @Noah: You are right the item base is the same, yet we would try different factor solutions on the same pool of 30 items - I think AIC and BIC would be suitable then?

Answer (score 5):

No.

For model B to be nested within model A, it has to be the case that model A can be made to be the same as model B by fixing some of A's parameters to a set value, typically 0 (removing a loading from CFA is equivalent to fixing it to 0).

What's more, you're not even using the same data for both models in this case, so they're definitely not nested!